# How to display only site root url in results from google custom search engine?

Tags: google-custom-search

How can I display only the root url in the google custom search engine results. Can somebody guide me?

[Google CSE http://www.danieldeepak.com/wp-content/uploads/test.jpg](http://www.danieldeepak.com/wp-content/uploads/test.jpg)

Comment: @haim770 : I want only the site root url to be displayed in Google custom search engine results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using simple CSS rules to hide the URL from the Google CSE.

Here's the relevant CSS, you can download the complete CSS from [www.labnol.org](http://www.labnol.org/)

[image]